# Can I force liquibase 3.5.1 to ignore legacy changeset checksum differences?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, liquibase

We're using liquibase 3.5.1 to help maintain mysql/mariadb installations across dozens of client computers.  Our stand-alone app creates a local DB and prepopulates that DB with 'seed' data.  With updates to mysql and some other tools we're using, we've been forced to alter some legacy liquibase changesets which obviously changes the checksums for these changesets.

We'd like to have liquibase completely ignore the changes to the checksums.

If it were just a couple of changes or even a lot of changes where a developer could intervene we would just update the databasechangelog table directly.  However, there are affected databases on clients' computers who would have no idea how to make the database changes needed.

I know about 'validCheckSum' and thought I could use 
--validCheckSum: ANY 
in the formatted sql files but that doesn't appear to do anything.

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset db-scripter:1
--comment: fixing issues with this after upgrading
--validCheckSum: ANY
INSERT INTO ...
```

'runOnChange' is also not an option as we don't want to rerun any of these old changesets (and insert twice the 'seed' data)

Are we missing any options here?   Or perhaps we're not using the validCheckSum correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and I solved using `clearCheckSums` command.

Comment: I appreciate the input...do you have an example of how you did this in a liquibase sql file?